# C# Print all items in an array that has repeated numbers. It only seems to print unique numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, printing, duplicates

I figured it out! Turns out it was printing to the console but it would print something like
1  (2)
2  (2)
3  (3)

Indicating each number had gone twice. If I print the numbers with the trial count I get what I am looking for
TC 1, Num 1
TC 2, Num 2
TC 3, Num 3
TC 4, Num 1
TC 5, Num 2
TC 6, Num 3

Thanks for all your suggestions.

---

I am new to `C#` and have run into an issue I can't seem to find the solution to.

I have a float array that has 6 slots, 3 of the slots are duplicated numbers
`( 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,1.0f,2.0f,3.0f)`.

I need to print out each of these numbers to the consul every time I hit "a".

The issue is that after the first 3 numbers it stops printing-- in the console I get :

> 1,2,3.... index out of range

I use the numbers in the array to change the size of an object. This object continues to change size with each "a" pushed so I know it is going through the whole array.

How can I get it to print the duplicates?

Here is a short version of my code, it has been shortened to remove irrelevant things.

```
*********************************************************************
public class ChangeSize : MonoBehaviour {
float[] numbers;

int MyIndex;
public int Range;

int trialCount = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () { //************************************Start

numbers = new float[] { 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,1.0f,2.0f,3.0f };

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    changeSizeObj();
}


//**************************************************Functions

void changeSizeObj() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
    {
        transformSize();
    }
}


void transformSize()
{

    float num = numbers[trialCount];
    print(num);

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(num, num, num);
    trialCount += 1;

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for the issue with the code. I'm not sure why 
         float[] numbers; 
is up there with 
         public class ChangeSize : MonoBehaviour {

Comment: how are you planning  to solve `3.999999f` and `4.0000001f` problem (round up errors problem)? Are you sure you have an array of **float**?

Comment: If you want to print the duplicates. You need to program it. You should create a list/hashset to keep track of the numbers you've already 'seen'

Comment: The key 'A' is checked every `Update` You might want to check if the key also is released. It might go too fast. There could be a delay on presenting the `print` values so the error is raised before all values are printed. You could test this by adding an debug delay `Thread.Sleep(1000)` for example. Better is to wait if the key is released.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I wasn't planning on solving the rounding issue as it didn't seem too big of a deal for what I am trying to do. And I am pretty sure that the array is a float array. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for your suggestions. The error only comes after I have hit the "a" key 6 times, which is the length of my array. I should have been more specific. However I will try your suggestion none-the-less. Also, can you go into more detail about the list, as I said I am new to this. Why do I need to keep track of the items I have seen if I just want to print the items already in my array. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To only print the duplicates, you could do something like this:

```
*********************************************************************
public class ChangeSize : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float[] numbers;
    HashSet<float> numberCheck;   // hashset


    int MyIndex;
    public int Range;

    int trialCount = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { //************************************Start

        numbers = new float[] { 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,1.0f,2.0f,3.0f };

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        changeSizeObj();
    }


    //**************************************************Functions

    void changeSizeObj() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            transformSize();
        }
    }


    void transformSize()
    {

        float num = numbers[trialCount];

        if (numberCheck.Contains(num))  // check for duplicates
            print(num);
        else
            numberCheck.Add(num);

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(num, num, num);
        trialCount += 1;

    }
}
```

// *******

Or make use of this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    HashSet<T> seen = new HashSet<T>();

    foreach (var item in items)
        if (seen.Contains(item))
            yield return item;
        else
            seen.Add(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
    // Use this for initialization
void Start () { //************************************Start

    numbers = new float[] { 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,1.0f,2.0f,3.0f };

    for(var num in numbers.GetDuplicates())
        print(num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this as I am sure it will be helpful in the future. It turns out my issue was much simpler than I though and I just didn't understand the console output. Thank you for your effort though.